# sustitución de registros específicos en un dataframe

Tags: python

estoy realizando una limpieza en una base de datos,y para ello quiero cambiar diversos registros de una columna según unas condiciones.

Adjunto parte del código donde intento realizar el cambio:

```
for i in range(len(alquiler)):
    if alquiler.iloc[i]['price']<=2000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=="":
        alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=media1
    elif alquiler.iloc[i]['price']>2000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['price']<=4000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=="":
        alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=media2
    elif alquiler.iloc[i]['price']>4000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['price']<=6000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=="":
        alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=media3
    elif alquiler.iloc[i]['price']>6000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['price']<=10000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=="":
        alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=media4
    elif alquiler.iloc[i]['price']>10000 and alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=="":
        alquiler.iloc[i]['floor_area']=media5
```

Donde para poneros en contexto, he definido varias condiciones y diferentes medias que es una variable con un simple valor numérico. Mi idea es que si se cumple la condición, ese registro cambie a algunas de esas medias, pero no me realiza el cambio.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero, no te recomiendo usar `for i in range(len(alquiler)):`, cuando tienes un método de `pandas` para iterar sobre filas: `for i, fila in alquiler.iterrows():`.

Segundo, creo que tu aproximación es más complicada de lo necesario. Me explico: estas iterando fila a fila en un dataframe, y en función a un conjunto de reglas decides qué valor sustituir (`media1`, `media2`...). ¿No sería más sencillo seleccionar de una tacada todas las filas de tu dataframe que cumplen la condición X y a todas ellas aplicarles el valor que quieres? Te adjunto un ejemplo de juguete para ilustrar:

```
condiciones_y_valor = tuple(
    [
        ("price <= 2000 and floor_area == ''", media1),
        ("price > 2000 and price <= 4000 and floor_area == ''", media2),
    ]
)

for condicion, media in condiciones:
    df_cumple_condicion = alquiler.query(condicion) # equivalente a tu if ... elif pero devuelve todas las filas del DF que cumplan 'condicion'
    alquiler.loc[df_cumple_condicion.index, 'floor_area'] = media
    # Si algún registro cumple la condición, cogemos su índice y sustituimos el valor de esa fila en el df alquiler
```